# angular ui grid repeats cellTemplates on virtual scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have tested an angular ui-grid cellTemplate on some of the columns and have noticed that on scroll the data is updated correctly by exception of the cells that display custom cellTemplates.

Here is the unwanted behaviour reproduced via plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/yXE3AuZEPwjlmlqpFTNq?p=preview

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.autoFitColumns','ui.grid.resizeColumns']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout) {
        var customTemp = '<img ng-init="url=COL_FIELD" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text={{url}}" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100">'
        $scope.gridOptions = {};

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

    });
  $scope.gridOptions.rowHeight = 50;  
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [

    { name:'eee' },
    { name:'age'  },
    { name:'address.street'}
  ];
  $scope.gridOptions2 = {};
  $scope.gridOptions2.data =[];
  $scope.gridOptions2.rowHeight =100;
  $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[];
  var timer = function() {


    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
        $scope.gridOptions2.data.push({
          value:i,
          name:'Name'+i,
          url:'https://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff&text='+i,
          image:i
        });

    }
    $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[{
      name:'image',
      cellTemplate:customTemp,
      width:100
    },
    {
      name:'name',
      cellTemplate:customTemp,
      width:100
    },
    {
      name:'url',
      width:50
    },
    {
      name:'value'
    }
    ];



  };

$timeout(timer,0);
console.log($scope.gridOptions);
console.log($scope.gridOptions2);
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/angular-ui-grid@latest/ui-grid.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular-ui-grid@latest/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/ui-grid-auto-fit-columns@latest/dist/autoFitColumns.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions2"
        ui-grid-auto-fit-columns
        ui-grid-pagination
        ui-grid-resize-columns
        class="full-height"></div>

    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"
        ui-grid-auto-fit-columns
        ui-grid-pagination
        ui-grid-resize-columns
        class="full-height"></div>      
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the directive in your plunker, i don't see it being used any where. What is the expected result?

Comment: @Raulucco Thanks for asking the directive I added in the plnkr is the solution to the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add a directive with a watcher on COL_FIELD:

working: plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yXE3AuZEPwjlmlqpFTNq?p=preview

js:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.autoFitColumns','ui.grid.resizeColumns']);


app.directive('myDirective', function ($log) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,

        scope: {
            url: '='
        },

        template: '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text={{url}}" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100">',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('url', function(newValue) {
            var url = newValue;
          });
        }
    };
});



app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout) {

  var customTemp = '<div><my-directive url="MODEL_COL_FIELD" /></div>';

  $scope.gridOptions = {};

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

    });
  $scope.gridOptions.rowHeight = 50;  
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [

    { name:'eee' },
    { name:'age'  },
    { name:'address.street'}
  ];
  $scope.gridOptions2 = {};
  $scope.gridOptions2.data =[];
  $scope.gridOptions2.rowHeight =100;
  $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[];
  var timer = function() {


    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
        $scope.gridOptions2.data.push({
          value:i,
          name:'Name'+i,
          url:'https://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff&text='+i,
          image:i
        });

    }
    $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[{
      name:'image',
      cellTemplate:customTemp,
      width:100
    },
    {
      name:'name',
      cellTemplate:customTemp,
      width:100
    },
    {
      name:'url',
      width:50
    },
    {
      name:'value'
    }
    ];



  };

$timeout(timer,0);
console.log($scope.gridOptions);
console.log($scope.gridOptions2);
}]);
```